# Run Script at fail login attempt?

Tags: bash, files, security, pam

Lately, I've been trying to create a Bash script to capture a webcam photo when a fail attempt to login is registered. First of all, I found 2 guides related to this (links at the end), they explained how to create script etc.. It was going pretty good until I noticed my System (Archlinux, Fresh installation) doesn't have PAM's common-auth file. I've checked the entire `/etc/pam.d/` directory and still can't find the file or a file with same contents.

My Script so far:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Let's watch our thief's face n.n


ts=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S")

ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -vframes 3 /home/haoa2/Logins-Fail/login-$ts.jpg

exit 0
```

My `/etc/pam.d/` directory contents:

`chage`,
`chfn`,
`chgpasswd`,
`chpasswd`,
`chsh`,
`groupadd`,
`groupdel`,
`groupmems`,
`groupmod`,
`login`,
`newusers`,
`other`,
`passwd`,
`polkit-1`,
`rlogin`,
`rsh`,
`shadow`,
`slim`,
`su`,
`sudo`,
`su-l`,
`system-auth`,
`systemd-user`,
`system-local-login`,
`system-login`,
`system-remote-login`,
`system-services`,
`useradd`,
`userdel`, and
`usermod`

[The orginal answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1509424&p=9827947#post9827947), and a [tutorial-like answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253189/can-i-make-the-webcam-take-a-picture-when-an-incorrect-password-is-entered).

(Note: I know there is a related answer out there, but this quetion is more about the PAM's file rather than Scripting.)

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Hi, I want to know, if there is a way to implement this on PAM since I can't find any file to add the lines for executing my script. :c

Comment: Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM) is a library that you need to get. Give me a few and I will look to see how to sudo-apt it

Comment: Looking at this link will provide you the downloads for PAM: https://packages.debian.org/stable/perl/libauthen-pam-perl

Comment: @ryekayo PAM is used by many applications, and it comes alongside Arch Linux. This is why the OP has a `/etc/pam.d` directory. Since PAM is getting more and more widely used, it would probably be ridiculous for a distribution not to provide it.

Comment: @ryekayo, `apt` is not fitting here since the user is on Arch Linux. Arch ships with PAM in [core]. The user already has it installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all**, if files are missing, it does not mean you should not create them. The `common-*` files available on Debian are just regular PAM configuration files, however, they are included in any other file which requires them. For instance, on Debian, at the end of the `su` file, you may find:

```
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
```

Since you don't have these files, I believe these include directives are not present. Since Arch's philosophy is to provide a minimal distribution, customisable by the user, you could perfectly create those `common-*` files and include them in those that are expected to use them.

**However in your case**, I would rather recommend that you target the PAM configuration file used at login (what you are trying to achieve is **not** a `common` operation, since it only targets the `auth` primitive, at login time). Have a look at `/etc/pam.d/login` and modify it in order to include your new PAM rule.

In my case, my `login` file ends with `@include common-auth`, which include the following chain. You should find something similar at the end of your `login` file.

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
```

Basically, this tries to authenticate against basic UNIX mechanisms (`passwd` and `shadow`). If it succeeds, then `success=1` will have PAM jump the next rule. In this case, `pam_deny` will be ignored, and we'll reach `pam_permit.so` automatically, allowing user access.

On the other hand, if `pam_unix` fails, there will be no jumping and the user will be sent straight to `pam_deny`. Since it is a requisite rule, the user will be denied access whatever happens next.

Finally, `pam_cap` is an optional rule which isn't really involved in the login process. However, it'll be executed whatever happens (which may be handy for logging). In your case, you could do something like...

```
# Jump two rules if login succeeds.
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    optional                        pam_exec.so [your cam script]
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
# User gets here if authentication is successful. No denying, no cam module.
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
```

If you're unfamiliar with PAM internals, I would recommend [this page](https://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-pam.html) which I found very helpful myself when I set up my PAM logic. Going through this page will definitely help you understanding how PAM works, and where to implement your logic precisely.

Another thing: you might want to make sure your camera is up to the task before running the script. Make sure the kernel video module is loaded, and so on.

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly what I need! And you're right, my su file doesn't have any @include's. I will read your link and modify /etc/pam.d/login file. Thank you! :DD

Comment: You're welcome. I added a little information about basic authentication behaviour through PAM on Debian (Ubuntu actually, but it does not matter here). It might help you placing your `pam_exec` rule at the right spot.